# Do I need to use verifyIdToken on the context.auth object in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Using a callable function, my intention is to only allow logged-in users to make calls to this.

```
export const sendMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
```

From the `context` param there, I have the auth token. But I'm just very new to firebase in general and I don't want to make a critical mistake by misunderstanding here. If I'm logged out, `context.auth` becomes null-- easy enough. But do I need to be sure that the auth token is valid and not "made up" by calling `verifyIdToken` anyway?

If not, then is simply checking that `context.auth` isn't null enough to be sure that the user is logged-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But do I need to be sure that the auth token is valid and not "made up" by calling verifyIdToken anyway?

No, that happens automatically.  You can be sure the `context.auth` is verified if not null.  As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

> The functions.https.onCall trigger automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens.

Comment: You are very gifted at finding exactly the right excerpt buried in the docs. I somehow always read past the one sentence I'm looking for.